# Save (already-existing) QSetting into an INI file

Tags: qt, ini, qsettings

I want to save an alredy-existing `QSettings` object into some INI file for backup.

The `QSettings` comes from the application's global settings, ie. it can be registry, ini file, etc.

---

In case it helps, my context is:

```
class Params
{
    // All params as data members
    // ...
    void loadGlobal ()
    {
        Qettings s; // Global parameters, paths set by application
        // Fill data members: s.value (...);
    }
};

class Algo
{
    Result run (Params p)
    {
        Result r = F(p);
        return r;
    }
};

int main (...)
{
    Params p;
    p.loadGlobal ();
    Algo a;
    Result r = a.run (p);

    // At this point, save Result and Params into a specific directory
    // Is there a way to do:
    p.saveToIni ("myparams.ini"); // <-- WRONG
}
```

---

A solution would be to add a `saveTo (QSetting & s)` method into the `Params` class:

```
class Params
{
    void saveTo (QSettings & s)
    {
        s.setValue (...);
    }
};

int main (...)
{
    Params p;
    p.loadGlobal ();
    QSettings bak ("myparams.ini", ...);
    p.saveTo (bak);
}
```

But I am looking for a solution without modifying the `Params` class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, no, QT Doesn't really support this directly.  I think your best bet is writing a helper class...something like:

```
void copySettings( QSettings &dst, QSettings &src )
{
    QStringList keys = src.allKeys();
    for( QStringList::iterator i = keys.begin(); i != keys.end(); i++ )
    {
        dst.setValue( *i, src.value( *i ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there are 2 issues:

- QSettings does not have a copy constructor or assignment operator (that I know of), so you'll probably have to write your own copy using **allKeys()**.
- You can't save QSettings to an arbitrary file, but what you can do is set the path used for a specific format and scope using the static method **QSettings::setPath()**. Note that you need to do that before your backup QSettings object is created (and you would use format **IniFormat**).

If you're OK not having complete control over the resulting path, this should be sufficient. If not, you could still do the above, then get the file name using **fileName()** and use a system call to copy/move the file to the desired final location.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time to answer. I agree with your 1st point. I do not agree with the 2nd, though: `QSettings` has a ctor accepting a file name as a parameter (where it will store its content). You can also use a combination of `QCoreApplication::setApplicationName()` and QCoreApplication::setOrganization*()` to precisely control the default path of `QSettings`

Comment: Sure enough... should always re-read the documentation before answering a question.